# Microsoft Decision Trees: support cases for a specific node

Tags: ssas, data-mining, decision-tree, dmx-ssas

I'm using Microsoft Decision Trees in Microsoft Analysis Services Data Mining, and need to show the historical data (the support cases from the training data used to train the decision tree) for a given leaf node in my mining model. Is there a way to access those records directly based on the NodeID using a DMX query, or is the only way to get the `NODE_DESCRIPTION` for the node, replace `not =` with `<>` and execute a query against my live database with that as my `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of rok1 on the MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatamining/thread/e6502263-a2b9-4fa1-b60b-04414e3efd29

```
SELECT * FROM [ModelName].Cases
where ISTrainingCase()
and IsInNode('0') --your intended node
```